# Managing unofficial repositories on a Debian system

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, repository

A few years ago I added this repository to my sources.list:

http://www.deb-multimedia.org/

because it contained packages like acroread or flash player, which were either missing or out of date in the official repos.

However, now I have just realized that some of the packages from that repository are broken, e.g. mencoder. Hence a few questions:

1. How can I find out which packages are installed from this particular repository?
2. How can I make this repository lower priority, so that only the packages I want are automatically installed/upgraded from there?

EDIT:
I edited `/etc/apt/preferences' file as someone suggested:

```
grzes:/home/ga# cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50

Package: *
Pin: origin deb-multimedia.org/
Pin-Priority: 50
```

but it didn't seem to work (note that I downgraded this package manually):

```
grzes:/home/ga# apt-cache policy mencoder
mencoder:
  Installed: 2:1.0~rc4.dfsg1+svn34540-1+b2
  Candidate: 3:1.1-dmo5
  Version table:
     3:1.1-dmo5 0
         50 http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ unstable/main i386 Packages
        700 http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ testing/main i386 Packages
 *** 2:1.0~rc4.dfsg1+svn34540-1+b2 0
         50 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main i386 Packages
        700 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.0~rc3++final.dfsg1-1 0
        600 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: You have multiple matching configurations (_release a=testing_ and _origin deb-multimedia.org/_). I guess the first pinning configuration is overwriting the latter one. Also I don't know if origin works with a '/' at the end, use the exact  string as reported by `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: Here, _http://www.deb-multimedia.org/_ has origin _www.deb-multimedia.org_ (note the _www_ at the beginning). After putting it at the beginning of the file it works.

Comment: @scai - I confirm that you are right, cheers!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer on superuser](http://superuser.com/a/138726/97195) how to search for all installed packages from deb-multimedia.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't have both the `origin` and `release` clauses at the same time. Every repository provides a label though, which can be used for filtering. In my case the correct `/apt/cache/preferences` file looks like this:

```
Package: acroread acroread-data acroread-debian-files acroread-dictionary acroread-dictionary-en acroread-escript acroread-fonts-jpn acroread-l10n acroread-l10n-en acroread-plugin-speech acroread-plugins cinelerra flashplayer-mozilla mozilla-acroread w32codecs
Pin: release a=testing,l=Unofficial Multimedia Packages
Pin-Priority: 550

Package: acroread cinelerra flashplayer-mozilla mozilla-acroread w32codecs
Pin: release a=stable,l=Unofficial Multimedia Packages
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: *
Pin: origin "www.deb-multimedia.org"
Pin-Priority: 50

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

To get the list of all available labels you need to run:

```
apt-cache policy
```

without specifying package name.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to list all packages and their repositories, but for a single one you can just execute `apt-cache policy <package>`. The line with the *** is the currently installed version with the corresponding repositories.

Setting the priority of a particular source is called [apt pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning) and can be done via */etc/apt/preferences* (newer [Ubuntu](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apt-Pinning) versions require the configuration to be in */etc/apt/preferences.d/* instead!):

You can pin either per *release*, *origin* or *version*. In your case, you want to pin either per origin:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin www.deb-multimedia.org
Pin-Priority: 300
```

or per release and the *o=* option:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Unofficial Multimedia Packages
Pin-Priority: 300
```

Note: It seems like the first matching pin configuration is used and additional matching configurations are ignored.

To see all currently known package sources, their priority, origins and other attributes, just call `apt-cache policy` without any option.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried the pinning, but it doesn't seem to work - see the edit to the question.

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting your answer, I found a better way to do it from apt maintainers...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script `apt-show-versions`.

```
apt-show-versions -b | grep deb-multimedia
```

would give you a list of packages from `deb-multimedia.org`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. `apt-show-versions` only shows if the package comes from testing/unstable etc, and not from which repository.

Answer (score 0):

2) You can find out which packages are installed from this particular repository with `aptitude` ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/132346/find-packages-installed-from-a-certain-repository-with-aptitude/138726#138726)).

```
aptitude search '~S ~i (!~Atesting ~Aunstable ~O"Unofficial Multimedia")'
```